# Is there a way to convert scientific notation to just the first few decimal places in Python?

Tags: python, notation

I have a list of 1111 values in scientific notation. Here are a few examples:

```
6.042968853864891e-12, 6.042894605467602e-12, 6.042777396826408e-12, 6.042616263531836e-12, 6.042410211830538e-12, 6.042158216350682e-12,
```

Is there a way I can convert this to just a list of 6.0429885, 6.04289460, 6.04277739,  6.04261626, 6.04241021, 6.04215821 (8 decimal places)? I don't want the scientific notation part (e-12).

I am ultimately trying to plot longitude on the x axis, latitude on the y-axis and have the points different sizes or colors based on density values (the density values are the numbers above in scientific notation). Here is a plot I have of just the longitude and latitude. I want to have this and each point be varying size depending on what the density is at that location.

[image]

Comment: Why? That would completely change the value

Comment: So, you want to extract the first 8 decimal numbers?

Comment: with list you mean you have already a python list of floats?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes I know it would. Ultimately I am trying to plot with scatter in matplotlib and want the sizes of the points to be corresponding to the scientific notation values. However, in scientific notation the size is to small to see on a plot.

Comment: @VasilisG. yes that's what I want to do

Comment: Then fix the plot boundaries

Comment: It sounds like you need to scale the plot itself. Can you post a quick example of the plotting with a canned dataset so we can see? I'd think that matplotlib would automatically scale it for you. You could multiply by `10**12` in this case, but scaling factor depends on the low and high values of your dataset.

Comment: This is kind of like plotting in meters when you really wanted picometers. Should you just rescale? Then fusion's answer is correct.

Comment: @tdelaney I just updated my post so you can see what I desire to do

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need to multipy these numbers by 1e12 then round to 8 decimal places, right?

```py
a = [6.042968853864891e-12, 6.042894605467602e-12, 6.042777396826408e-12, 6.042616263531836e-12, 6.042410211830538e-12, 6.042158216350682e-12, 
]

b = [round(i*1e12,8) for i in a]

# if you want to scale your plot, then you shouldn't need to change the list itself, rather do this to your plot:

# if you have an ax, do:
ax.set_ylim([0,1e-11]) 
# this will give you a fixed y axis limit between 0 and 1e-11.
```